# Azure AD B2C Custom Policies: Add hyperlink to custom attribute ClaimType

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is there a way to add a hyperlink to a custom policy ClaimType? For example, if I need a user's consent to agree to terms of use, how can I provide a link to the terms of use inline with the check box label?

In my custom policy (base xml) I tried adding the following:

```
<ClaimType Id="extension_TermsOfUseConsent">
  <DisplayName>Agree to Terms of Use</DisplayName>
  <DataType>boolean</DataType>
  <UserInputType>CheckboxMultiSelect</UserInputType>
  <Restriction>
    <Enumeration Text="I agree to the &lt;a href='https://...'&gt;Terms of Use&lt;/a&gt;" Value="true" SelectByDefault="false" />
  </Restriction>
</ClaimType>
```

But it renders on the page like this

```
I agree to the <a href='https://...'>Terms of Use</a>
```

I can understand why it's doing that but I'm wondering if there is an alternative. Adding it to a custom template places it below the `api` div and does not make it very clear for the user.

I used this link for reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-create-custom-attributes-profile-edit-custom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to add a hyperlink to a custom policy ClaimType?

Not today.

If there the user experience is acceptable to you, you could add a text above api div with the URL to the page of your choice and add some appropriate text, e.g. "In order to proceed, you must agree to our terms and conditions" (with "terms and condition" hyperlinked).

Then the checkbox could just have "I agree to terms and conditions". That checkbox can be recorded in the directory.

Comment: [Uservoice idea](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/32705134-enable-hrefs-in-b2c-custom-ui-and-custom-policies) to add this

Comment: Related [Uservoice idea](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/17044282-terms-of-use-and-privacy-policy): Terms of use and privacy policy for SignUp

Answer (score 2):

1. Add link in your design (HTML, CSS) into outer scope of `<div id="api">...</div>`.
2. Move your `<a href="..."></a>` to your checkbox with CSS.

Comment: It's been a while since I posted this question. I'm assuming I need JavaScript to move the link. Is JavaScript supported now?

Comment: Looks like it is still in private preview: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br

Comment: It is now in public preview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples